# Comparing Snapshot Data in Excel (VBA?)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I’m currently working on a project which leverages live trading data (RTD) within MS excel 2016. I’m struggling with how to continuously take snapshots of dynamically updating volume data (single cell) to calculate the difference between “last” and “current”.

e.g. Cell A1 continuously adds trades to its aggregate total. First trade is 100, second trade is 300, third trade is 200…total is 600…and so on. I simply need to take a snapshot of the last updated total and compare it to the most recent updated total. This function needs to handle approximately 2-3 updates per second.

Current – Last = Difference in Volume Total (or last trade amount)

Any help would be appreciated as I’ve already burned a few hours on this task.

Comment: Snapshot = Cells(1, 1).Value  will capture the value of A1 at the moment the code is run. If you run it on a Worksheet_Change event responding to changes made to A1 perhaps automatically you can evaluate the Snaptshot in which ever way you want.